# mvc two areas with same name in different project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, controllers, areas

I have a project with the following structure:

Solution
- CMS.core
---Areas
------Admin
---------Controllers
- Site.Web
---Areas
------Admin
---------Controllers

Everytime I try to route to a controller under `site.web/areas/admin/controllers` it appears to only look in `cms.core/areas/admin/controllers`.

Does this make sense? How do I route mvc to multiple areas of the same name located in different projects?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the namespace in which the controller resides.. for example:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "SiteWebAdminRoute",
    "site.web/areas/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    new { Area = "SiteWeb", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new string[] { "Site.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers" });
```

..or something similar. Notice the string array down the bottom though. If you look in the Intellisense, it shows you that this string array represents any namespaces where this route should look for controllers. You can do the same with your other area route.. except you would provide a different namespace to look in.

Comment: i have tried providing the namespace but am still getting a 404 when i try to go to a controller inside the site.web/area/admin/ area...

i can't figure out how to add code blocks to replies on this site...

Comment: Edit your original question with any extra code. Can you provide the URL you're trying and both of your routes for both areas?